# Which browsers support the `<img srcset...>` attribute?

Tags: html

The [`<img srcset...` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/) allows different images to be shown to the user dependant on screen resolution.

Which browsers currently (Jan 2013) support this attribute?

Given that this is a useful attribute for users browsing on smartphones, additionally, which mobile browsers offer support?

Comment: [`caniuse.com`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) is a great source for *browser compatibility*.

Comment: Yep that's a great resource but real picture could be different.

Comment: I've recommended https://html5test.com/compare/feature/responsive.srcset.html in an answer below. I just also looked at caniuse.com, nice tabular view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated Feb 2014**

There are various aspects to `srcset`, including pixel density and viewport width. At the time of writing:

- viewport width *isn't* supported by the current versions Safari, Chrome or Firefox
- pixel density is supported by Chrome

I've put some test files and results on a [Github repo](https://github.com/michrome/srcset-browser-support) which I'll try to keep current.

Comment: WebKit [added support](https://www.webkit.org/blog/2910/improved-support-for-high-resolution-displays-with-the-srcset-image-attribute/) on Aug 12, 2013.  This means it will probably supported Safari version 7 (from Mavericks), but I'm unsure of Mobile Safari.

Comment: I've updated my Github repo. It's not yet in Safari 7. Also, I notice [Surfin' Safari](https://www.webkit.org/blog/2910/improved-support-for-high-resolution-displays-with-the-srcset-image-attribute/) only mentions pixel density, not viewport width.

Comment: FYI… another article, [WebKit Has Implemented srcset, And It’s A Good Thing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/webkit-implements-srcset-and-why-its-a-good-thing/) by chair of the W3C’s [Responsive Images Community Group](http://responsiveimages.org).

Answer (score 4):

Webkit is now supporting the srcset attribute: https://www.webkit.org/blog/2910/improved-support-for-high-resolution-displays-with-the-srcset-image-attribute/

Comment: And (as of today) Chrome: http://blog.chromium.org/2014/02/chrome-34-responsive-images-and_9316.html

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, wikipedia seems to be using srcset with attributes like this:

```
srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Izokefalizm.jpg/300px-Izokefalizm.jpg 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Izokefalizm.jpg/400px-Izokefalizm.jpg 2x"
```

I'd guess they are using a polyfill to achieve this, but it certainly is displaying larger images correctly. Might be worth poking around.

Comment: Yes, it's a polyfill, see http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResponsiveImages
and
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/HiDPI_display_support

Comment: a what-y-fill you ask : http://elroyjetson.org/dev-notes/mobile/implement-responsive-images-with-a-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices - Safari for iOS8 now supports srcset - but won't be generally available until the Fall 2014.

http://friendfeed.com/christianoliff/c7c40ae2/safari-for-ios8-now-supports-img-srcset

Comment: but only the resolution `1x` and `2x` and not the `w` notation

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for the current support at [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset). As of now, October 2015, if you don't care about IE as much, you can safely use it on pretty much all browsers, good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

A "correct" answer would have to evolve over time.

A candidate test site: https://html5test.com/compare/feature/responsive.srcset.html